# A brain dead student trying to connect 2 different JavaClass

Tags: java

**my teacher gave me this and I don't know how to connect deposit and checkBalance. I tried stuff on youtube and it did not work so I'm stuck.**

**Code 1:**

```
package compositionPT;

import java.io.*;

public class BankMainClass {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
             
        String name = "Dave";
        String pin = "84448";
        double balance = 69000.00;
        Bank b1 = new Bank(name, pin, balance);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String enteredPin = br.readLine();
        if(b1.checkPin(enteredPin)){
            b1.displayMenu();
            System.out.print("> ");
            byte choice = Byte.parseByte(br.readLine());
            switch(choice){
                case 1:
                    System.out.print("Enter your amount: ");
                    double withAmount = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
                    b1.withdraw(withAmount);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // your code here
                    break;
                case 3:
                    // your code here
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.print("Thanks for choosing us. Good Bye!: ");
                    break;
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Invalid Pin!");
        }    
    }
}
```

**Code 2**

```
package compositionPT;

import java.util.Scanner;

public final class Bank {

    private final Account account;
    private static Scanner in;
    private static int anotherTransaction;

    public Bank(String name, String pin, double balance){
        this.account = new Account(name,pin,balance);
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        display();
    }
    public void withdraw(double amount){
        double newBalance = account.getBalance() - amount;
        account.setBalance(newBalance);
        System.out.println("Your balance: $" + account.getBalance());
        double balance = 69000;
        
        if (amount > balance || amount == 0) {
                    System.out.println("You have insufficient funds\n\n");
                    anotherTransaction();
                } else {
                    balance = balance - amount;
                    System.out.println("Transaction Complete!");
                    System.out.println("You have withdrawn " + amount + " and your new balance is " + balance + "\n");
                    anotherTransaction();
        }
    }
    
    public void deposit(float amount){
        double newBalance = account.getBalance() - amount;
        account.setBalance(newBalance);
        System.out.println("Your balance: $" + account.getBalance());
        float deposit; double balance = 69000;
                System.out.println("Please enter amount you would wish to deposit: ");
                deposit = in .nextFloat();
                balance = deposit + balance;
                System.out.println("You have deposited " + deposit + " new balance is " + balance + "\n");
                anotherTransaction();
    }
    
    
    public void checkBalance(){
        String balance = null;
        System.out.println("Your balance is " + balance + "\n");
                anotherTransaction();
                
                System.out.println("Invalid option:\n\n");
                anotherTransaction();
    }
    
    public void displayMenu(){
        System.out.println("Welcome to CP11b Bank");
        System.out.println("Select a transaction");
        System.out.println("[1] Withdraw");
        System.out.println("[2] Deposit");
        System.out.println("[3] Check Balance");
        System.out.println("[4] Exit");      
    }
    
    public void display(){
    System.out.println("Enter your pin: ");
    
    }
    
    public boolean checkPin(String enteredPin){
        String truePin = account.getPin();
        return enteredPin.equals(truePin);
    }

    private static void anotherTransaction() {
        System.out.println("Do you want another transaction?\n\nPress 1 for another transaction\n2 To exit");
        anotherTransaction = in .nextInt();
        switch (anotherTransaction) 
        {
            case 1:
                
            break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Thanks for choosing us. Good Bye!");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid choice\n\n");
                anotherTransaction();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**I want to connect Case 2 to deposit and Case 3 to checkBalance but because I can't think straight I don't know what I should do.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you seem to be asking how to call the `deposit()` and `checkBalance()` methods from a Bank object.

Take a look at `case 1` where they invoke the `withdraw()` method on the `Bank` object `b1`. When you use the dot operator, you can call the objects methods. So `b1.withdraw(withAmount);` is invoking the `withdraw()` method from the `Bank` object `b1`.